# How "--keepdb" affects setUpTestData?

Tags: django

From the Django documentation I see that a Django [TestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#testcase) wraps the tests within two nested atomic() blocks: one for the **whole class** and one for **each test**.

Then I see that [setUpTestData](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData) method "allows the creation of initial data at the class level, **once for the whole TestCase**": so we're talking about the whole class atomic block.

This means that the [--keepdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-keepdb) flag should not affect this behaviour, because what this flag do is just skip the database create/destroy.

But **I noticed that if I run the test with the --keepdb flag the data I create in the setUpTestData method are preserved**.

I'm fine with this but I want to understand what --keepdb exactly does, because I can't understand why this happens. I tried to look directly at the Django TestCase class source code but I don't see any check about the --keepdb option.

Why - if I run my test with the --keepdb option - the data I create in setUpTestData method are preserved?

Comment: When you create data in `setUpTestData` it's written to the test DB, if you pass the `--keepdb` flag the test DB (and all the data it contains) is not destroyed or recreated so the data "persists". Is that what you are asking? Are you expecting the data to not be preserved?

Comment: @IainShelvington exactly, I expect the data to not be preserved because the setUpTestData() is called in an atomic transaction, so there is a rollback in the tearDownClass() method

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was right: the --keepdb option **doesn't** affect the setUpTestData behaviour.

I deleted my test database, so now I'm starting from scratch.
Now I see that all the data I create in setUpTestData are "rolled back" after the TestCase ends, also with the --keepdb option.

Probably I just messed up my test database before.